# Changing analogue ammeter scale from 1A to 1mA

Tags: amperage, meter

How can I change analogue panel ammeter for metering 1A DC scale to 1mA DC ?

As far as I know, you can use shunt resistor for doing this other way around, but this doesn't help much.

Thank you

EDIT:
PART CODE: DHMINI1A
SPECIFICATIONS:

Range:  0-1 A
Type of current:  DC
Accuracy:  CLASS 1.5
[image]

[image]

Comment: The meter should have an internal shunt resistor. You might be able to dig in there and modify it.

Comment: Use a DC amplifier.

Comment: Can you post the meter's data sheet, or a link to it, or manufacturer and part number?

Comment: Such meters are USUALLY but NOT always higher sensitivity meters + shunt. Without modifying the meter you MUST supply 1a FOR FULL DEFLECTION WHICH YOU'D WANT T AVOID.  aS emf SAYS - PART # BRAND ETC.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an ordinary moving coil meter- there should be a resistor internally (probably across the terminals inside the back 'hump'). You can try to open it, figure out the shunt and increase it. No way does 1A flow through the moving coil.

However, the movement itself may be closer to 10mA than 1mA- a higher current (within reason) is useful because it makes the movement more rugged, so you may open (and perhaps ruin) the meter for nothing.

Take extreme care with the movement itself- bending the hairspring so the turns touch or getting debris into the movement will adversely affect the linearity and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ekl9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Internal diagram of high-current meter.*

Your meter probably consists of a low-current milli-amp meter in parallel with a high current shunt. Your only hope of making the instrument more sensitive is to remove the shunt and test it's sensitivity by connecting it up to a power supply through a current-limiting resistor.

- If its sensitivity is still to low then you probably can't go any further.
- If its sensitivity is too high you then need to figure out what resistance in parallel will cause full scale deflection at 1 mA.
- There's always a chance that it will be exactly right.